# How to get difference in value over a sliding time window?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm attempting to write a SQL query which returns every **product** where the most recent  price on an **order** within the last 30 days is different than the most recent price in the previous 30 days, and that calculated variance. I'm currently using PostgreSQL 11.

#### Data Model

Right now, the data is structured into three tables: `orders`, `products`, and a pivot table, `order_product`. Here is the simplified version of the table structure:

##### Orders

| id | order_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-15 |
| 2 | 2022-02-15 |
| 3 | 2022-03-08 |

##### Products

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Some product |
| 2 | Another product |
| 3 | Yet another product |

##### Order_Product

| order_id | product_id | unit_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 20 |
| 1 | 3 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 2 | 20 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 | 15 |

#### Desired Output

The desired output would be something like the following:

| id | name | order_date | latest_unit_price | previous_unit_price | variance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Some product | 2022-03-08 | 15 | 10 | 5 |
| 3 | Yet another product | 2022-02-15 | 5 | 10 | -5 |

### What I've done so far

I've been able to write a join that combines the Orders and Products via the `order_product` table, within the 60-day window, which is seemingly the easy part:

```sql
SELECT
    "products"."id",
    "products"."name",
    "order_product"."unit_price",
    "orders"."order_date"
FROM
    products
    JOIN order_product ON products.id = order_product.product_id
    JOIN orders ON order_product.order_id = orders.id
WHERE
    order_date BETWEEN now() - INTERVAL '60 days'
    AND now()
```

I've been trying to work with `RANK()` and `LAG()`; however, where I'm getting stuck is being able to find the rank the rows *within* the 30-day time windows, and then calculate the variance between the two windows.

Any help would be much appreciated!

### Update: Added solution

Building off of the answer by [D-Shih](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5176071/d-shih), I had to tweak this to work based on the time window starting from the current date:

```sql
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        "products"."id",
        "products"."name",
        "order_product"."unit_price",
        "orders"."order_date"
    FROM
        products
        JOIN order_product ON products.id = order_product.product_id
        JOIN orders ON order_product.order_id = orders.id
    WHERE
        order_date BETWEEN now() - INTERVAL '60 days' AND now()
),
CTE2 AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        EXTRACT(DAYS FROM now() - order_date :: timestamp) gap_days
    FROM
        CTE
),
CTE3 AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        (CASE WHEN gap_days < 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) grp
    FROM
        CTE2
)
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 1 THEN order_date END) order_date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 1 THEN unit_price END) latest_unit_price,
    MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 0 THEN unit_price END) previous_unit_price,
    SUM(CASE WHEN grp = 1 THEN unit_price ELSE - unit_price END) variance
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, grp ORDER BY order_date DESC) rn
        FROM
            CTE3
    ) t1
WHERE
    rn = 1
GROUP BY
    id,
    name
HAVING
    MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 1 THEN unit_price END) <> MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 0 THEN unit_price END)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6fc6064a359be319a456347c68a1732b)

Comment: What are you defining as "variance"? The statistical term cannot be negative, but you said in your example that the "variance" is `-5`. Do you mean the difference between the current price and the last price? If it's a concept that is different than statistical variance, I'd recommend changing its name.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant. I will update the name, thanks.

Comment: Why didn't  `product2` show in your expected result?

Comment: Because there was no change in `unit_price`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `EXTRACT` with `LAG` window function to get days difference from `order_date` and previous `order_date` each `productId`.

Then use `SUM` aggregate condition window function to calculate the `group`

- `grp = 0` within the last 30 days
- `grp = 1` most recent price in the previous 30 days,

the query would be look like as below.

```
WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT  "products"."id",
    "products"."name",
    "order_product"."unit_price",
    "orders"."order_date"
 FROM
    products
    JOIN order_product ON products.id = order_product.product_id
    JOIN orders ON order_product.order_id = orders.id
 WHERE
    order_date BETWEEN now() - INTERVAL '60 days'
    AND now()
), CTE2 AS (
  SELECT *,EXTRACT(DAYS FROM  order_date - LAG(order_date,1,order_date) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY order_date)) gap_seconds
  FROM CTE 
), CTE3 AS (
  SELECT *,(CASE WHEN SUM(gap_seconds) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY order_date) > 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) grp
  FROM CTE2
)
SELECT id,
       name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 1 THEN order_date END) order_date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 1 THEN unit_price END) latest_unit_price,
       MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 0 THEN unit_price END) previous_unit_price,
       SUM(CASE WHEN grp = 1 THEN unit_price ELSE - unit_price END) variance
FROM (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID,grp ORDER BY order_date DESC) rn
  FROM CTE3
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY id,
         name
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 1 THEN unit_price END) <> MAX(CASE WHEN grp = 0 THEN unit_price END)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=06ae46857cd8ff83c4adb4f63ee11c6f)

Comment: This was extremely helpful, but I believe it was creating a time-window based on the latest `order_date`, and not the current date. What I ended up going with is: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6fc6064a359be319a456347c68a1732b